# How do I move a Pose Bone on its local axis?

Tags: python, scripting, bones, pose-mode, axis

All I want to do is move the active pose bone on its local z axis with a line of code.
[image: Text]
I tried many things, but no matter what I can only get it to move in world space or move the whole armature in local space.
I'm sure I'm missing something stupid. Some line of code that specifically applies to bones? It can't be that hard, can it?